# 16.04 - openJDK 7 - Minecraft Won't Launch

Tags: java, launcher, minecraft

Its used to work.  However, when I press the play button on its launcher, it's keeps popping up with this output shown here [image: Picture]

Comment: NO story please, none of use like reading stories. Just keep it to the point and belief.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with the 1.12 update, Minecraft started requiring Java 8. Make sure you have the latest version of Java installed on your computer as this may be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo apt install openjre8` in the terminal